# Click event for custom controls added in ConfigureExtraProperties - abp framework

Tags: c#, abp

I have added few custom controls in the Identity user form using abp framework using ConfigureExtraProperties. I have added a check box and dropdown.

I need to do some validations when the check box is checked or when the dropdown is selected.
Also I should display the control based on the condition. Please let me know how to achieve this task.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.